# Django Custom Inclussion Tags

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use custom inclusion tag to display the latest 3 post titles on my blog sidebar, I don't seem to get any errors but my results didn't display either.

templatetags.py

```
from django import template
from ..models import Post

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('blog/post/latest_posts.html')
def show_latest_posts(count=5):
    latest_posts = Post.published.order_by('-publish')[:count]
    return {'latest_posts': latest_posts}
```

[Inclusion tag in latest_posts.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzz7s.png) 
latest_post.html

```
<ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[templatestag.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67vcF.png)

base.html

```
{% load blog_tags %}
{% load static %}
<h3>Latest Posts</h3>
{% show_latest_posts 3 %}
```

[including the template in base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5NNP.png)

and this is my file structure

```
blog/
  templates/
    blog/
      post/
        lastest_posts.html
      base.html
  templatetags/
    __init__.py
    blog_tags.py
```

Comment: what are your latest_posts.html file. I can not understand it from screenshot. Also you need to add your code as code block(not using images). This is common rule for community

Comment: Alright. I am new here but I've added the code blocks now, check again, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your template is wrong. Just change posts to latest_posts

```
<ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```